# How to remove 2 or more spaces with a character at start and end in linux

Tags: awk, sed, replace, command-line, command

I have lots of text files and in some lines, my content is as below:

```
, +


                        304685593
                        2,
```

The result of cat -A has been shared as below:

```
, +$
              $
               $
                304685593$
                2,
```

But I want to only have exactly the below content :

```
, 304685593,
```

I used the below commands and it didn't work, really appreciate it if anyone can give me a hint?
I want to remove if more than 2 spaces and also remove the first plus and the last character after more than 2 spaces.

```
find . -name "*.txt"  | xargs sed -i.bak -e 's/+ \{2,\}/ /g;s/\{2,\}1/ /g;s/\{2,\}2/ /g;s/\{2,\}3/ /g;'
```

Comment: Try `sed -Ez 's/(^|\n),[^[:alnum:]]*([0-9]+)[[:space:]]{2,}[0-9],($|\n)/\1, \2,\3/g'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This is not working no changes have happened. is it possible to consider spaces except new lines?

Comment: You showed a single line in input or input with multiple lines?

Comment: @anubhava: It is multiple lines. but i want to know can we consider multiple spaces too?

Comment: Can you show output of `cat -A file` in question

Comment: @anubhava: I have shared it above in the question.

Comment: ok thanks. Does it always start and end with a comma?

Comment: @anubhava: yes always.

Comment: Did you try it with your options combined? `xargs sed -i.bak -Ez 's/(^|\n),[^[:alnum:]]*([0-9]+)[[:space:]]{2,}[0-9],($|\n)/\1, \2,\3/g'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To run this in `find` command try following(written and tested with shown samples). I would strongly recommend to test this command in first 2 o3 3 test files in test directory once happy then you could run on actual files please.

First create `script.awk` as follows(`cat` command following is NOT the code its to only show the content of `script.awk`):

```
cat script.awk
BEGIN{
  RS="^$"
}
{
  gsub(/\n+[[:space:]]+\n+|\n+[[:space:]]+$/,"")
  gsub(/\n+[[:space:]]+|\+[[:space:]]+/,OFS)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+[0-9]+,/," ,")
  $1=$1
}
1
```

Then run following `find` command to do in-place update in files.

```
find . -name "*.txt"  -exec \
     bash -c 'awk -f script.awk "$1" >"$1".tmp && mv "$1".tmp "$1"' _ {} \;
```

---

---

***To run only on single file:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS="^$" '
{
  gsub(/\n+[[:space:]]+\n+|\n+[[:space:]]+$/,"")
  gsub(/\n+[[:space:]]+|\+[[:space:]]+/,OFS)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+[0-9]+,/," ,")
  $1=$1
}
1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu-awk`, you may use this with a custom `RS`:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|\n),[^,]+,(\n|$)' 'RT {
    $0 = RT
    gsub(/[[:space:]]{2,}/, "")
    sub(/\+/, " ")
} 1' ORS= file
```

```
,  4771481792,
```

Comment: sorry if my question is basic. but how i can give my input file and apply this command to getting output?

Comment: You can see that this command is accepting a file as argument in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^, \+$/{:a;N;/,.*,/!ba;s/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/,\1,/}' file
```

Gather up the lines between two commas, remove everything but the first set of digits and surround the result with commas.

Alternative:

```
sed -zE 's/, \+\n[^,0-9]*([0-9]+)[^,]*,\n/,\1,/' file
```